# Using a get:set to return and refer to items after the conditions have been met

Tags: c#

I'm un sure how to return the 'product names', based on the user input for product ID.
I would like to have the correct 'product names' returned if the conditions are met.

Properties for product id and product category name. Assume that:
The set accessor will always receive a product id of a valid format that has a length that is 4.
The first letter is lowercase, the second letter is a hyphen and ends with two digits. For example, 'e-11' and 'b-22' are of valid format and refer to known categories 'Electronics' and 'Books'.
If the product id does not refer to a known category, then the set accessor must retain the number and assign to the 'o-' category. For example, 'q-23' will be assigned as 'o-23'.
The category property is a read-only property that is assigned a value when the product id is set.

```
 public static string[] categoryCodes = { "e-", "b-", "a-", "t-", "o-" };//Two public static arrays that hold codes
public static string[] categoryNames = { "Electronics", "Books", "Apparel", "Toys", "Others" };//Two public static arrays that hold codes
private string productCategoryName;//Data fields for product name 
private string productID // Data fields for product id
{
    get { return productID; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Length == 4 && Char.IsLower(value[0]) && value[1] == '-' && char.IsNumber(value[2]) && char.IsNumber(value[3]))
        //Properties for product id and product category name
        {
            productID = value;
            productCategoryName = (value[0]);// im unsure how to have this refer back to the categories.
        }

        else
        {

            productID = "o-" + value.Substring(1);
            productCategoryName = "Others";
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Look into [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) and [Array.FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex). Using these two methods, you should be able to find the index of categoryCodes, which should map to the same index in categoryNames

Comment: I'm wanting Assign category name based on the first letter of product ID

Comment: By the way, you have a stack overflow in your code. You have a property `productID` referring to itself in its `get`ter. When someone tries to read `productID`, your code will try to read that property (and so on). Similarly if someone tries to set the `productID` property, your code will try to set that property. Try looking up `Dictionary <char, string>` as a way to store your property info (rather than parallel arrays). For example, map `'b'` to "books", `'e'` to electronics and `'o'` to "other".